# Measure inequalities and sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let A, B, C any three random events in (Ω, F, P). Prove that \br

|P(A ∩ B) − P(A ∩ C)| ≤ P(B △ C)

I thought the right way to compute this exercise was to use the fact that: \br

1. (A ∩ B) − (A ∩ C) = A ∩ ( B\C)
2. B△C = (B\C) U (C\B)

So in conclusion I can say that A ∩ ( B\C) is surely < than (B\C) and  (C\B) is surely greather or equal to 0, so i'm done.
Is this correct? My doubt are on the first point. Is this applicable also on the measures or only on sets? What about the abs value, how do I have to treat it?

ThankS!

Answer (score 1):

1. is true but 2.  is false.

$P(A\cap C) \leq P(A\cap B)+P(C\setminus B)$ because $A\cap C \subseteq (A\cap B)\cup (C\setminus B)$. Similarly, $P(A\cap B) \leq P(A\cap C)+P(B\setminus C)$ because $A\cap B \subseteq (A\cap C)\cup (B\setminus C)$.

$P(A ∩ B) − P(A ∩ C)\leq P(B\setminus C)\leq P(B\Delta C)$ and
$P(A ∩ C) − P(A ∩ B)\leq P(C\setminus B)\leq P(B\Delta C)$. Can you finish?

Comment: I'm sorry, i got confused. I wanted to prove exactly what you wrote at the end

Comment: I edited right now the post, sorry again. May you please help me?

Comment: Should I finish the exercises just bringing, in the second sentence, P(A∩C) to the left and so i have my inequality proved? Now i can conclude just by saying that P(B\C) is added with something greater than 0, so the inequality always holds. P(A∩B) - P(A∩C) ≤+P(B∖C) + P(C∖B)(certainly greater than 0) so it's ok

Comment: Pretty sure there is more to prove than that.. perhaps you missed the absolute value part?

Comment: I suppose that the abs part is shown in the first sentence, because: P(A∩C) - P(A∩B)≤+P(C∖B), but for the abs value, i can switch the two intersection

Comment: It should be already finished, I think. I only have to get rid of the P(B∖C) or P(C∖B) but i can do it thanks to the squeeze. Like to say 3<5<8, so 3<8!